# Permutations in lexicographical order with not unique characters

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, permutation

I want to make function to output all possible permutations from input string, in lexicographical order.

I have the following code:

```
void permutations_print(char *permutations, int index, int length) {
    if (index == length) {
        printf("\"%s\"\n", permutations);
    }
    for (int i = index; i < length; i++) {
        rotate(permutations, i, index);
        permutations_to_array(permutations, index + 1, length);
        rotate_back(permutations, index, i);
    }
}

void rotate(char to_swap[], int i, int j) {
    char temp = to_swap[i];
    for (int k = i; k > j; k--) {
        to_swap[k] = to_swap[k - 1];
    }
    to_swap[j] = temp;
}

void rotate_back(char to_swap[], int i, int j) {
    char tmp = to_swap[i];
    for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
        to_swap[k] = to_swap[k + 1];
    }
    to_swap[j] = tmp;
}
```

The input string permutations is permutations_print is sorted.

It works without any issues for permutations with just unique characters, but I need it to work also for character non-unique strings, any ideas how to tweak it / modify it / to work? I have to use recursion and should not use any kind of sorting and I should not store it in any array, just print. And I want to print all, even duplicates.

Comment: You may want to start with an array that gives the number of occurrences of each character in the string (i.e., using the character as an index into the array). That will help you produce the permutations in the correct order.

Comment: Update: I was able to do it using that strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: not a C programmer, so my code can definitely be improved.

You can do it iteratively with something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void swap(char* array, int i, int j);
void reverse(char* array, int left, int right);
bool nextPermutation(char* array, int n);
int compareCharacters(const void * a, const void * b);
void printPermutations(char *permutations, int length);

int main() {
    char myArray[] = "hey";
    printPermutations(myArray, 3);

    return 0;
}

void printPermutations(char *array, int length) {
    qsort(array, length, sizeof(char), compareCharacters);
    *(array + length) = '\0';

    do {
        printf("%s\n", array);
    } while (nextPermutation(array, length));
}

int compareCharacters(const void * a, const void * b) {
     return (*(char*)a - *(char*)b);
}

bool nextPermutation(char* array, int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    // Find index, swapIndex1, of rightmost number that has a number greater than it
    int swapIndex1;

    for (swapIndex1 = n - 2; swapIndex1 >= 0; --swapIndex1) {
        if (array[swapIndex1] < array[swapIndex1 + 1]) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (swapIndex1 == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    // Find index, swapIndex2, of smallest number to the right of that and greater than it
    int swapIndex2 = swapIndex1 + 1;
    int minToRight = array[swapIndex2];

    for (int i = swapIndex2 + 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if (array[i] <= minToRight && array[i] > array[swapIndex1]) {
            minToRight = array[i];
            swapIndex2 = i;
        }
    }

    // Swap values at swapIndex1 and swapIndex2
    swap(array, swapIndex1, swapIndex2);

    // Reverse values from swapIndex1+1 to n-1
    reverse(array, swapIndex1 + 1, n - 1);

    return true;
}

void swap(char* array, int i, int j) {
    char temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

void reverse(char* array, int left, int right) {
    for (; left < right; ++left, --right) {
        swap(array, left, right);
    }
}
```

The algorithm is described [here](https://www.quora.com/Whats-an-algorithm-to-print-the-permutations-of-a-string-without-recursion/answer/Anders-Kaseorg?srid=3gl4). See the comments section for an example/explanation, or see transcription below:

> Let's pretend we're finding the next largest permutation of digits from 1-9.
>
> For example, suppose we have: 123479865
>
> We want to find the smallest number greater than 123479865 that can be obtained by rearranging the digits of 123479865.
>
> What this means is that we have to make at least one digit bigger than it currently is.  If we had our choice, we would want to make the rightmost digit bigger since that will result in the smallest change.  If we were to make a left number bigger, it would result in a bigger change in value.
>
> e.g.: 12347986**5** => 12347986**6** is a much smaller change than **1**23479865 => **2**23479865.
>
> Therefore, we want to find the farthest digit to the right that we can make bigger.  In order to make a digit bigger, we have to find another number bigger than it within our sequence and then swap the two.
>
> Note: we cannot swap a number (e.g., 5) with a number to its left (e.g., 6), because then we would be decreasing the value of a digit to our left, which would make our overall number smaller.  For example, if we swapped 5 with 6, we would get 1234798**56**, which is smaller than 1234798**65**.  Thus, we always swap with a number to our right.
>
> So let's go through 123479865, starting with the rightmost digit.
>
> There is nothing bigger than 5 to the right of 5, so we can't make 5 bigger.
>
> Now let's consider 6.  There is nothing bigger than 6 to the right of 6, so we can't make 6 bigger.
>
> Now let's consider 8.  There is nothing bigger than 8 to the right of 8, so we can't make 8 bigger.
>
> Now let's consider 9.  There is nothing bigger than 9 to the right of 9, so we can't make 9 bigger.
>
> Now let's consider 7.  There are a few numbers to the right of 7 that are bigger than 7, namely: 9 and 8.  Therefore, we can make 7 bigger.  We want to make it bigger by the least amount, so we should swap it with the smallest value that is bigger than 7.  In other words, we should swap 7 with 8.  That gives us: 1234**8**9**7**65.
>
> The number 123489765 is bigger than 123479865, but we can actually make it smaller while maintaining that it's bigger than 123479865.  We can do this because we now have infinite freedom to change any of the following digits: 12348**9765** (anything to the right of 8).  Those numbers can be as small as possible because the 8 to their left ensures that the new number is always bigger.
>
> The best way to make the digits 9765 smaller is to sort them in increasing order, giving us 5679.  Sorting works because the leftmost place values contribute the most to the overall value.  Therefore, we want the leftmost digits to be the smallest digits.
>
> That leaves us with 12348**5679**, which is our answer.
>
> Note: we don't actually have to sort the numbers to the right of 8.  We can actually reverse their order because we know that the numbers from the right side to 8 are in increasing order (because earlier, we stopped the first time we got to a number that was smaller than its previous number).